# Adding SQLAlchemy records with Formalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, formalchemy

I am trying to use Formalchemy to add a new record to my SQLAlchemy table `DataTBL`.

```
fs = FieldSet(DataTBL)
fs.bind(DataTBL, request=requestobject)

if fs.validate():
    fs.sync()
    session.commit()
```

This gives me a validation error because the DataTable object is still empty...

```
ValidationError: Cannot validate without binding data
```

How do I use Formalchemy to start with an empty form that has the DataTBL structure, fill the form and validate/submit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a request.POST to use .validate()

Try:

```
fs = FieldSet(DataTBL)
fs = fs.bind(DataTBL, request=requestobject)

if requestobject.POST and fs.validate():
    fs.sync()
    session.add(fs.model)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: This `fs = FieldSet(DataTBL, request=requestobject)` instead of `fs = FieldSet(DataTBL)` made it work.

Comment: oh, yes. .bind() return a new instance so it should be `fs = fs.bind(DataTBL, request=requestobject)`